# bash script tr -d [:punct:] does not work

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

This command isn't work on my laptop how I'd expect it to since it doesn't remove the punctuation characters.

```
echo "asdaftafiatfiat!!!~~~$$$$tt" | tr -d [:punct:]
```

However `tr -d [:punct:]` remove `t` from the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [quoting issues](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html), your shell is interpreting `$` and `!` because you are using double quotes. You need to use single quotes to avoid any character being interpreted with `bash`:

```
$ echo 'asdaftafiatfiat!!!~~~$$$$tt' | tr -d [:punct:]
asdaftafiatfiattt
```

Comment: I try your method am it didn't work. I think is something wrong with my laptop because it remove all the 't' from each letter instead of special charaters

Comment: That does not mean something is wrong with your laptop, that is to be expected as the `t` follow the characters that get interpreted. The simple case is `echo "$t"` which echo's the shell variable `t` but as the does not exist an empty string is printed (not the variable name `t`). Are you sure you are using `bash` what does `echo $0` say?

Answer (score 0):

I think your tr doesn't recognize classes like [:punct:], but try quoting it perhaps:

```
... | tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

If you find difficulty with bash's history expansion you can disable it:

```
shopt -u -o histexpand
echo 'asdaftafiatfiat!!!~~~$$$$tt' | tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

Comment: @Sycx I hope you could vote my answer up to get the unfair negative mark out if you found my answer helpful thanks.